# How to sum up the nth column with the n+1th column in a dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe, sum, multiple-columns

How can i sum up the **n** th column with the **n-1** th column in a dataframe for a subset of columns?

For example i have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID          C1  C2  C3 
1   2000-12-24  3d  2d
2   2000-12-24  2d  1d
```

i want R to do the following:

```
ID C1         C2                        C3           
1  2000-12-24 2000-12-24+3d=2000-12-27  2000-12-27+2d=2000-12-29
2  2000-12-24 2000-12-24+2d=2000-12-26  2000-12-26+1d=2000-12-27
```

so that the final dataframe looks like this:

```
ID  C1          C2          C3          ...
1   2000-12-24  2000-12-27  2000-12-29
2   2000-12-24  2000-12-26  2000-12-27
```

UPDATE:

The data has been generated accordingly:

```
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)
Heterotransaction <- rgamma(2,shape=3 , scale=1)
ID <- list(1:2) 
Elog <- data.frame(ID,Heterotransaction)
Elog$fist_transaction <- "2000-12-24"
Elog$fist_transaction <- as.Date(Elog$fist_transaction, "%Y-%m-%d")
Heterotransaction <- rgamma(2,shape=3 , scale=1) 

f.transaction <- function(x){
  y<- (rexp(2,x))
duration(y, units = "years")
}

tbtrans<-ldply(Heterotransaction, f.transaction) 
purchases<-data.frame(ID,tbtrans) 
Elognew<- merge.data.frame(Elog, purchases)
```

Comment: Do you have `3d` `2d` etc or simply `3` `2` in your original dataset.

Comment: Since im not used to R i don't know how to explain in what format they are, but hope the updated code above will give you the needed information.

Comment: Please check the update. I got the expected output as you showed for the 2nd set of example.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
 df1[3:ncol(df1)] <- lapply(3:ncol(df1), function(i) rowSums(df1[2:i])) 
 df1
 #  ID C1 C2 C3
 #1  1  2  5  7
 #2  2  4  7  8
```

or

```
 df1[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, cumsum))
```

Or another option would be to use `Reduce`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[,2:ncol(df1) := Reduce(`+`, .SD, accumulate=TRUE),
                       .SDcols=2:ncol(df1)][]
 #   ID C1 C2 C3
 #1:  1  2  5  7
 #2:  2  4  7  8
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset, one option would be to modify the first solution

```
 df2[3:ncol(df2)] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(3:ncol(df2), function(i) 
     as.Date(df2[,2]+cumsum(as.numeric(sub('[^0-9]+', '', df2[,i]))))))
 df2[3:ncol(df2)] <- lapply(df2[3:ncol(df2)], as.Date, origin='1970-01-01')

 df2
 # ID         C1         C2         C3
 #1  1 2000-12-24 2000-12-27 2000-12-29
 #2  2 2000-12-24 2000-12-26 2000-12-27
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, C1 = c(2L, 4L), C2 = c(3L, 3L), 
C3 = c(2L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "C1", "C2", "C3"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- df2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, C1 = structure(c(11315, 11315),
class = "Date"), 
C2 = c("3d", "2d"), C3 = c("2d", "1d")), .Names = c("ID", 
"C1", "C2", "C3"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your helpful comment! But i still couldn't solve my problem, since i don't have numeric values in my specific case. In C1 i have a date like 2000-12-24 and then in the following columns C1, C2... days.. In the end i want to come up with just dates in every column.. C1= 2000-12-24, C2=2000-12-24+2d=2000-12-26 and C3=2000-12-26+5=2000-12-31.. Sorry for beeing not specific enough!!

Comment: @dschn My code is based on your input dataset and expected one.  If you have a different kind of data, why don't you post an example and expected code based on that.

Comment: @dschn Please do update your post.  I think it is possible after converting the column to `Date` class and then add

Comment: Sorry, i didn't want to make it too complicated, that's why i made this more simple example before.

Comment: @dschn Yes, then nobody know what the original class of your columns will be